# Extract String via google sheet formular

Tags: google-sheets

I have this string:

localhost,GEWTESTID,something,else

The text can be like this, but it can also have fewer values and the order can also be different, like:

GEWTESTID,yesnomaybe

I want to extract GEWTESTID.

GEWTESTID always starts with GEW
and after GEW always 6 chars following.

I tried with SEARCH and LEFT but I can't get the result I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Try Regex: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

Comment: Assuming your text is in cell A1, you can use: `=mid(A1,search("GEW",A1,1)+3,6)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "GEW.{6}")
```

[image]

Comment: And to play around with Regex, try this for fun: https://goldenlion5648.itch.io/regex-adventure-browser